# Unable to set name of a thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am learning Thread in Java and have a small program like this. I create one thread and use it to create another thread. However I can not change the name of the second thread. Can anyone explain why it is like that ? Also, is it correct that Thread.sleep(100) means the main thread will sleep for 100 msec. Thanks.

```
class Thread1 extends Thread{
   public void run() {      
      for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        System.out.println(getName()+" is running. Time is "+i);
      }
   }
}

public class Program{   
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {        
       Thread t1 = new Thread1();
       t1.setName("Thread 1");
       Thread t2 = new Thread(t1);
       t2.setName("Thread 2");
       t1.start();
       Thread.sleep(100);       
       t2.start();      
    }       
}
```

The results from this program are:

```
Thread 1 is running. Time is 0
Thread 1 is running. Time is 1
Thread 1 is running. Time is 0
Thread 1 is running. Time is 1
```

Edit: If I change getName() to Thread.currentThread().getName() then everything work as expected. What is the differences between them ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
   Thread t1 = new Thread1();
   t1.setName("Thread 1");
   Thread t2 = new Thread(t1);   <--- See this.
```

You are passing the same previously created thread instance (t1) to the next thread instance(t2). That is why same name is coming.

This should have been like this:

```
   Thread t2 = new Thread1();
   t2.setName("Thread 2");
```

Output:

```
Thread 1 is running. Time is 0
Thread 1 is running. Time is 1
Thread 1 is running. Time is 2
Thread 1 is running. Time is 3
Thread 1 is running. Time is 4
Thread 2 is running. Time is 0
Thread 2 is running. Time is 1
Thread 2 is running. Time is 2
Thread 2 is running. Time is 3
Thread 2 is running. Time is 4
```

> Also, is it correct that Thread.sleep(100) means the main thread will sleep for 100 msec.

Yes. That is correct. `Thread.sleep(milliseconds)` takes the parameter in milliseconds.

---

When you pass a `Thread` instance while creating a Thread object. This new thread will use the passed instance for execution (as a Runnable instance). That is why you are getting the `Thread 1` and where as the running thread is different, newly created thread instance. So the Thread.currentThread().getName() will give you the name you have set.

```
public class Thread implements Runnable {
....
....

/* What will be run. */
private Runnable target;       // <-- Runnable is defined here for the thread.


public Thread(Runnable target) {  //<-- constructor you are calling.
    init(null, target, "Thread-" + nextThreadNum(), 0); //<-- internal init call.
}

private void init(ThreadGroup g, Runnable target, String name,
                  long stackSize) {
    init(g, target, name, stackSize, null);  //<-- internal init call.
}

private void init(ThreadGroup g, Runnable target, String name,
                  long stackSize, AccessControlContext acc) {
.....
.....
this.target = target;     // <-- Set the Runnable for the thread.
.....
}
....
....
}
```

Comment: Thanks @YoungHobbit. If thread 2 is created from thread 1, does that mean thread 1 and thread 2 are basically the same ? I just updated my question. When I change the method from getName() to Thread.currentThread().getName() then everything works as expected.

Comment: If thread 2 is created from `t1` as you did it, it means that thread 2 will run as a separate thread but execute whatever is in `t1`. So when it executes `getName()` it gets the name from `t1`. It's still a separate thread, but executing the same code as the other one.

Comment: @Steven: Thread extends Runnable. when you pass t1 as a parameter to t2, t1 is treated as a Runnable by t2, its being a Thread is not relevant to anything, you are just confusing yourself.

Comment: @Steven  I have added the internal method call, how this is happening and running the thread. hope this will clear the confusion for you. You can also check the code of the `Thread` class. The explanation provide by `Erick G. Hagstrom` and `Nathan Hughes` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

when we are creating thread object, JVM assings default name for that thread.
Default thread name assigned by JVM are look like - Thread-(int Value) for e.g Thread-0,Thread-1 etc.

---

if we want to use our own name for the thread instead of using default name then we can use constructor of Thread class by passing our own name as parameter.

`class MyThread extends Thread{
        ..
        MyThread(String tname)
        {
        super(tname);
        }
        }
        ..
        MyThread th=new MyThread("My-Thread");`

---

If we want to change the name of thread after creating thread object with some name then we can use the method - public final void setName(String name)